# Proof of an Inequality

Tags: inequality

Given a sequence $(b_n)_{n=1}^p$ of positive numbers such that $b_1>b_2>\cdots>b_p>0$, define 
$$\beta=\bigg(p!\frac{p}{p-1}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{\min\limits_{1\leq k\leq p-1}{(b_k-b_{k+1})}}}.$$
Suppose $a_i\in\mathbb{C},i=1,2,\cdots,p$ satisfies $|a_i|>\beta|a_{i+1}|, i=1,2,\cdots p-1$ and $|a_p|>1$. Prove the following matrix
$$ D=
\begin{pmatrix} 
a_{1}^{b_1} & a_{1} ^{b_2}& \dots & a_{1} ^{b_p}& \\
a_{2} ^{b_1}& a_{2} ^{b_2}&  \dots &a_{2} ^{b_p}\\
                                \\
a_{p} ^{b_1}&  a_{p} ^{b_2}&  \dots & a_{p} ^{b_p}
\end{pmatrix}$$
satisfies the following inequality:
$$\frac{1}{p}\prod_{i=1}^{p}|a_i|^{b_i}<|\det(D)|<2\prod_{i=1}^{p}|a_i|^{b_i}.$$

Comment: If Riemann can't solve it, what can we do? :) Sorry for the off topic, couldn't resist.

Comment: What is the context for this inequality? Why it should be true?

Comment: Writing \det with a backslash in $\TeX$ does not just prevent italicization; it also provides for proper spacing and is standard usage.  Correct: $a\det A$.  Incorrect: $a det A$.  I editing the question accordingly.

Comment: this question is from Graduate Admission Test for the AMSS OF CAS! www.amss.ac.cn